# What does this groupby function mean I have done?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

I have 3 columns: topic, year and country. 
I am trying to find the maximum number of topics per country over the years and want it to group by the maximum project count for each country.

I've used this groupby function below:

```
df.groupby(['topic', 'year', 'country']).count()
```

However I can't really tell what it is showing me as it has just grouped each topic with each year and the country. I don't have another column for count also as I would like to see how many per topic so I have numbers to plot later also. How do I do this?

```
topic              year       country
Mechanics         2014.0         FI
                                 IT
                  2015.0         NL
                                 UK
                  2016.0         FR
                                 UK

biochemistry       2014.0        DE
                   2015.0        AT
                                 BE
                                 DE
                                 DK
                                 ES
                                 FI
                    2016.0       AT
```

Comment: could you show what the output is?

Comment: Please add a sample of what your `df` looks like to the question.

Comment: That's a portion of my output and what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

that groupby should give you the count of each unique tuple of `('topic', 'year', 'country')`

Comment: But how do I get only the unique tuple for just topics. and only the topic count and as another column?

Comment: @s.23 that's odd - could you post a snippet of your data as well?